# Count positive values for each column in all dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to count positive values of each column in a dataframe ?

I tried to do this with 'count'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(18)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10,10,size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

print(df)
   A  B  C  D
0  0  9 -5  7
1  4  8 -8 -2
2 -8  7 -5  5
3  0  0  1 -6
4 -6  1 -9 -7


positive_count = df.gt(0).count()

print(positive_count)
A    5
B    5
C    5
D    5
dtype: int64
```

The "gt" (greater than) seems doesn't work.

I tried with 'value_counts', and it works for column 'A' in this example

```
positive_count = df['A'].gt(0).value_counts()[1]
```

But I would like to get this result for all columns at one time.

Does anyone have an idea to help me?

Comment: `df.gt(0).sum()` do a sum of booleans instead of count

Comment: Many thanks @anky, It works perfectly !

Comment: No problem, count just ignores `np.nan` by default , to make count work you have to replace anything which doesnt meet the condition by nan , like `df.where(df.gt(0)).count()`

Comment: I see. Thanks for this precision